# LINQ to Entities split string on result

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, orm

I have a LINQ statement as follows:

```
var playedBanDataList =
    from bannedPlayers in query
    select new PlayerBanData
    {
        Admin = bannedPlayers.Admin,
        BannedUntil = bannedPlayers.BannedUntil,
        IsPermanentBan = bannedPlayers.IsPermanentBan,
        PlayerName = bannedPlayers.PlayerName,
        Reason = bannedPlayers.Reason,
        IpAddresses = bannedPlayers.IpAddresses.Split(new [] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    };

    return playedBanDataList.ToList();
```

This fails because split function fails on `IpAddresses` as LINQ to Entities cannot translate this query to SQL.

This makes sense, but then what's an equivalent way of accomplishing this elegantly? The only way I've thought of is to manually run a loop on the retrieved string then splitting it, but I'd like to get it in one go.

Comment: You might want to first execute the query before doing foreach on it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That's exactly what I want to avoid doing in the first place, unless if there are no other ways around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `AsEnumerable` to make the select occur in memory instead of EF.

```
var playedBanDataList = query.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(bannedPlayers => new PlayerBanData
    {
        Admin = bannedPlayers.Admin,
        BannedUntil = bannedPlayers.BannedUntil,
        IsPermanentBan = bannedPlayers.IsPermanentBan,
        PlayerName = bannedPlayers.PlayerName,
        Reason = bannedPlayers.Reason,
        IpAddresses = bannedPlayers.IpAddresses.Split(
            new [] {","}, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    });
```